# Is there any governmental organization/party in europe that has a main goal to untangle eu from US?

Tags: united-states, european-union, international-relations, parties, europe

Well ever since the US decided to step out of the climate accord, I've been wondering whether some consider the US the biggest enemy of Europe. Considering climate change will hit Europe hard and there is no way to protect ourselves without large sacrifices.

Then there is the Iran deal, when after a decade of talks there was finally an agreement with Iran, only for the US to unilaterally step out of the deal leaving the whole economy in limbo.

Finally I notice that the Iraq/Syrian refugee crisis seems an effect of a war that raged for way too long in Syria. Where also the US played a role, yet the US didn't take responsibility by taking in refugees or pay for the damages done.

---

I understand that historic events have led the EU and US to take steps to integrate our economies more and more. Given the above, however, I am wondering whether there
is any party in Europe that advocates the untangling of EU-US cooperation in terms of economic and military cooperation?

Comment: It's hard to see this question being asked in good faith considering the use of words.

Comment: This question contains some curious proposals. For instance, you seem to think that US researchers are "stealing" the knowledge and "historical data" of Europe, which you propose to fix by preventing them from going to the US. I can tell you that's not how scientific research works. Researchers around the world, in Europe, the US, but not only there, share research, which improves the rate of scientific and social development. Most of this is done online, and has little to do with attending conferences in person.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as primarily opinion based, given the stilted nature of the premise. Further, the many claims made here, without citation, could themselves be questions on this platform. At its base, it misunderstands the nature of US Government; since neither the Paris Accords or the JCPOA were ratified by the US Congress, they had no weight beyond the previous administrations departure.

Comment: You also argue for economic isolation from one of the largest markets in the world as a cure for what ails you.  Maybe you should ask Donald Trump how that's working? Moreover, Europe will experience the effects of climate change regardless of their interactions with the US, or China, or India. You can't use isolationism to save yourself from the environment. Besides, perhaps Europe should be careful about throwing the first stone. Germany, say, is #6 in emissions, with emissions per capita worse than China and others, and several other European countries are in the top 20.

Answer (score 1):

Absent any other answers, I'm going to say **no, there's no such party in Europe with any significant following**. Rather than going off all the parties one by one, I'm going to provide some basic geopolitical arguments as to why this is a bad idea. My reasoning is that basing a party on that wouldn't be useful electorally, as people will see those downsides, without (m)any upsides.

### Defense

The US and EU cooperate closely on defense. Most EU member states as well as the US are part of NATO. With the US being the biggest member of NATO, untangling the EU from the US will put pressure on that relationship.

### Climate

In your question you mention climate, which is a long term problem. One might argue that the current US administration doesn't do much toward that, but it would be silly to break ties over that. The reason it's silly is because you won't get something better in return.

It's not like the US is going to make changes because Europe broke ties, to the contrary, as long as there are strong ties one can persuade the other more easily to listed to one's position.

Comment: Well I'd foresee if we break ties we no longer have to stop creating nuclear and biologic weaponry which currently the US forbids us from creating. We can ally with other countries to make weaponry that can hurt the US and make them change.

Comment: Right, because nuclear weapons will help the environment?

Answer (score 1):

The EU is a [net exporter to the US](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/USA-EU_-_international_trade_in_goods_statistics), so this proposed economic "untangling" would likely hurt the EU economically to a substantial degree, leaving aside the geopolitical/strategic aspects. This is probably why no party even the nationalistic ones in Europe seem to seriously propose it.

There is some anti-US sentiment in Europe though, or at least [anti-US-policies sentiment](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F2158244015584163), and it has existed for some time:

> The term anti-Americanism has become common in public and academic debate in the last decade. Yet we have only limited knowledge of those who hold such views. From 2003, 2005, and 2006 Eurobarometer data, almost 20% of European Union (EU) respondents disapproved of U.S. policy in all five dimensions the surveys examined. Following the literature, this consistent opposition is defined as anti-American. Anti-Americans exhibit systematic differences in age, education, geographical location, policy preferences, and nationality. In addition, although anti-Americanism is associated with a preference for greater European independence, perhaps surprisingly, it is also linked to a desire for a less federal and hence less powerful Europe.

On the other hand, on more localized issues, e.g. US troops in Iceland, there surely are parties that have made a platform of evicting the US (and actually [leaving NATO](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1038463/EU-news-Iceland-European-Union-Nato-membership-membership-rejection-latest-EFTA-Norway) as well).

But speaking of NATO, the ruling parties in most of continental Europe don't have much trouble of talking of more European defense integration, even an ["European army"](https://www.politico.eu/article/angela-merkel-emmanuel-macron-eu-army-to-complement-nato/) to "complement" NATO (in Merkel's words), although it never seems to get too far in practice...